# How to retrieve column value from Pandas dataframe and check condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe column Class consists of 2 values 0 and 1.I want to count how many rows are present for Class 0 and how many rows for Class 1.I wrote code like this

```
genuine_count=0
fraud_count=0
if credit_card_df['Class'] == 1:
    fraud_count +=1
else:
    genuine_count +=1
print "Genuine transactions"+genuine_count
print "Fraud transactions"+fraud_count
```

I am getting this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2e8ec920b69d> in <module>()
      1 genuine_count=0
      2 fraud_count=0
----> 3 if credit_card_df['Class'] == 1:
      4     fraud_count +=1
      5 else:

C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
    890         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    891                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 892                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    893 
    894     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Kindly help me resolve.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thankfully, `pandas` has already written this for you:

```
credit_card_df['Class'].value_counts()
```

Alternatively, if you want to print in your own format:

```
genuine_count, fraud_count = credit_card_df['Class'].value_counts(sort=True)

print "Genuine transactions"+genuine_count
print "Fraud transactions"+fraud_count
```

Comment: I think you can just unpack the output with `genuine_count , fraud_count 
 = credit_card_df['Class'].value_counts()`, and then print. Great idea tho.

Comment: That was actually my first option, but I wasn't positive the Series returned by `value_counts()` would always be sorted. I guess we could do that explicitly, since that is always better than implicit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
fraud_count = (credit_card_df['Class'] == 1).sum()
genuine_count = (credit_card_df['Class'] == 0).sum()

print "Genuine transactions {}.".format(genuine_count)
print "Fraud transactions {}.".format(fraud_count)
```

I hope this helps.